# How to modify an adress ip in hex?

Tags: c

I am displaying  adress ip  of some network nodes with using a network simulator, But I don't have the expected result.

I display ip adress with using this function:

```
void print_hex_src_adress(uint8_t *s, size_t len)
{
    printf("  ID=");
    for(int i=0; i< len; i++) {
        printf("%02x", s[i]);
    }
}
```

Then in order to display the adress I put:

```
open_addr_t * myaddress;
myaddress = idmanager_getMyID(ADDR_64B);
print_hex_src_adress(myadress, 16);
```

But the result that I have is not the expected result:

```
  ID=02141592cc0000000400000093947ae2
```

the expected result is:

```
  ID=02141592cc0000000400000000000000
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186540/discussion-on-question-by-user6594048-how-to-modify-an-adress-ip-in-hex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`idmanager_getMyID`](http://openwsn-berkeley.github.io/firmware/structopen__addr__t.html) returns a pointer to a union of type [`open_addr_t`](http://openwsn-berkeley.github.io/firmware/structopen__addr__t.html). A union is an object big enough to hold any of the fields it could contain. That does not mean that all the data in it will be initialized. You are requesting `ADDR_64B`, which means that only the first 64 bits, or 8 bytes, of the union are likely to be initialized via the [`addr_64b`](http://openwsn-berkeley.github.io/firmware/structopen__addr__t.html#a7883e2f04b296c641bc4c24de62d6387) field.

What is effectively happening is that you are invoking undefined behavior, trying to print bytes that contain trash values. The good news is that you won't run into memory that you aren't allowed to use because the union is at least 16 bytes. You are expecting the trash to be zeros, but instead are getting actual trash. You have two options:

1. Print the bytes you actually requested:

   ```
   print_hex_src_adress(myadress.addr_64b, sizeof(myadress.addr_64b));
   ```

   Using `sizeof` for something like this is a good habit to have. Structures and unions can change between versions, but writing it like this makes your code mode robust against such changes.
2. Request the bytes you actually want:

   ```
   myaddress = idmanager_getMyID(ADDR_128B);
   ```

   Still refer to the correct field when you print, and don't hard-code the size so much:

   ```
   print_hex_src_adress(myadress.addr_128b, sizeof(myadress.addr_128b));
   ```